# How do I combine 4 excel cells into one but ignore cells with particular data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula that will combine 4 excel cells that contain dates into one statement, but if the cell has "No Promo" in it, then I want the formula to ignore this cell.  I would also like to cell to place "to" inbetween the first date and the last date.  If there are 3 dates, then I want the result to choose the first date and the last date.
There will always be 4 cells. There will always be at least 2 dates.
I tried a formula I pulled from this site.

```
=IF(V24="","",V24)&IF(AND(V24<>"",V25<>""),", ","")&IF(V25="","",V25)&IF(AND(V24&V25<>"",V26<>""),", ","")&IF(V26="","",V26)&IF(AND(V24&V25&V26<>"",V27<>""),", ","")&IF(V27="","",V27)
```

This formula rendered the 4 cells together but I am not sure how to ask it to ignore the No Promo

[image]

@Artiic Scenario #2 worked below.  However, if all 4 cells contain "No Promo", I would like the answer to be "No Promo" or "-".

@p._phidot Your formula did not work?  It delivered a 06/24/23FALSE07/01/23FALSE.  Maybe I input incorrectly.

Comment: Are those actual dates? (i.e. cells in date format in Excel)

Comment: Actually it will be the 8 digits on the right. 07/24/21
08/07/21
NO PROMO
NO PROMO

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem? Just to confirm, will there always only be 4 cells or could there be more (maybe not important)? Will there always be at least 2 dates? When you say to ignore `NO PROMO` is it that same as saying ignore any cell(s) in the range that does not have a date? For any responses to comments please EDIT your question.

Comment: Change the `IF(V24="","" .. ` & `IF(OR(V24="",V24="NO PROMO"),"" .. ` (for all instance)should do.. | does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem, but with the limited details in the OP, I've had to assume some criteria and still had two different possible scenarios based upon the information provided.  I've hosted the sample .xlsx file [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-6S_C33etbQoErHcv1buo2TArfDBXVFd) in case you'd prefer to download and modify as needed.

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: Although your OP stated that there would not be any such cases, here's a revised formula that would still perform the previous function, but also check for instances where all four cells contain "NO PROMO" as well:

`=IF(AND((Z10="NO PROMO"),(Z11="NO PROMO"),(Z12="NO PROMO")*(Z13="NO PROMO")),"NO PROMO",((TEXT((MAX(AB10:AB13)),"mm/dd/yy")&" to "&TEXT((MIN(AB10:AB13)),"mm/dd/yy"))))`

Comment: A formula as text in the answer would be useful.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I did include the sample worksheet, so that they can be copied directly from the cells if desired.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be so short in last comment - was at the end of the work day.  I meant that formula, etc in the question as text will always be there and easy to read and copy.  In five or ten years the link to your spreadsheet will probably be broken and the solution will be lost to anyone down the line that needs it, and some websites are blocked in work places.

Comment: Scenario #2 above worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.  This is a life saver.

Comment: @Artiic Question...How would you add to your Scenario #2 if the 4 cells were "No Promo" (no date)?  I am trying to put in Iferror but it is not working?  the answer I get is 01/00/00 to 01/00/00.  I would like to get "No Promo" or "-".

Comment: @DebB Please find edited answer for modified formula per your request.  Apologies for the delayed response, I just got back from a trip out of town.